# java контрольная сумма при помощи гибких ссылок

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,  я написала код для вычисления контрольной суммы 
при помощь гибких ссылок, но не могу понять почему у меня выдается ошибка в данной части кода.**bufferRef.set(byteArray);** не могли бы вы объяснить в чем причина.

```
package ru.j4web.examples.java.io;

import java.io.File;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference; 

public class n {

    private static final String FILENAME ="C:\\Users\\E\\Desktop\\"
            + "1.zip";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File file = new File(FILENAME);
        System.out.println("Файл: " + FILENAME);
        if(file.exists()) {
            final double bytes = file.length();
            System.out.printf("Размер файла в байтах: %.0f\n",
                    bytes);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Файл не существует.");
        }
    }
}


class CachingChecksum {
    private SoftReference<byte[]> bufferRef;


    public synchronized int getFileChecksum(String FILENAME) {

        int len = getFileSize(FILENAME);
        byte[] byteArray = bufferRef.get();
        if (byteArray == null || byteArray.length < len) {
            byteArray = new byte[len];
           bufferRef.set(byteArray);
        }
        readFileContents(FILENAME, byteArray);
        // calculate checksum and return it

    }

    private void readFileContents(String fileName, byte[] byteArray) {
        // TODO Автоматически созданная заглушка метода

    }

    private int getFileSize(String fileName) {
        // TODO Автоматически созданная заглушка метода
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Желательно привести стактрейс ошибки

Comment: он запускает программу пишет что 1 ошибка но не указывает ее. а в коде высвечивается красным эта строка и там пишется что **Метод set(byte[]) не определен для типа SoftReference<byte[]>;** но даже делая что он просит ошибка не убирается

Answer (score 1):

1. У объекта класса `SoftReference<byte[]>` нет метода `set(byte[] bytes)`
2. Переменная `bufferRef` нигде не объявлена